# Xamarin Forms CollectionView with square images

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I want to display list of images as a grid with several rows (2 or 4) with Xamarin Forms. Each cell of the grid must be square. I'm using CollectionView with vertical layout, required span and fixed HeightRequest in DataTemplate. I get multicolumn grid, but I cannot make images (cells) to be squared.

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image
                        HeightRequest="100"
                        x:Name="imageCell"
                        Aspect="AspectFill"
                        Source="{Binding .}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Set the WidthRequest equal to your HeightRequest

Comment: @SushiHangover cell width has to be equal to the half (one fourth) of the page. Should I calculate it in runtime and pass to the data template from view model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to other answers, I've ended up with custom ContentView setting up HeightRequest equal to Width and the image inside it.

```cs
    public class SquareView : ContentView
    {
        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
            HeightRequest = Width;
        }
    }
```

and XAML

```xml
<CollectionView
                ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        Span="2" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:SquareView>
                            <Image
                                HeightRequest="20"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                Source="{Binding .}" />
                        </views:SquareView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!
However, in my case `HeightRequest = Width` was sometimes ignored. Adding `await Task.Yield()` before that line made it more stable for me. Alternatively, it can be wrapped in `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, [see the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578905/5655977).

Comment: @Sourcerer, you are a sorcerer indeed! Have my sincere gratitude, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced a small sample.

Only thing I added was to wrap the image inside a contentview, to apply a padding (which you can ignore)

```
 <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView Padding="0">
                    <Image Source="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzJUY4JZTX9oYsSl1jclFvdsoXhtA0AfxqKkYX2P81Qb3cyX9o"
                           HeightRequest="150"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           />
                        </ContentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<Image></Image>` as your root layout in DataTemplate.
Instead, use one of the Layout controls (StackLayout, AbsoluteLayout etc.) or ContentView and then apply some styles or whatever you prefer to this root layout of your CollectionView.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackLayout>
      <Image
         HeightRequest="100"
         x:Name="imageCell"
         Aspect="AspectFill"
         Source="{Binding .}" />
   </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why? Adding additional nesting is generally not recommended for performance? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance