# Xamarin calculating a stack layout height at run time

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to create a dynamic view, where I get the data from the backend and create views for it on my Xamarin App.

In the XAML view I have a simple stack layout

```
<StackLayout x:Name="Container">
</StackLayout>
```

and I am creating views as soon as the date is retrieved as so

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text= Text;
label.LineHeight = 1.1;
Container.Children.Add(CreateLabel(label));
```

The problem is the view doesn't expand to fit all the elements added

calculating the height and setting it as the HeightRequest for stack layout didn't work

any idea or suggestion would be nice.

Comment: have you tried setting the VerticalOptions for the StackLayout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic HeightRequest not working for StackLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445744/dynamic-heightrequest-not-working-for-stacklayout)

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo for you by writing the MainPage.xaml.cs file.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        String Text1 = "This is a text. This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.";
        Double LineHeight1 = 1.78;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var layout = new StackLayout {  };
            var label = new Label { Text = Text1, TextColor = Color.Black, FontSize = 20, LineHeight = LineHeight1, BackgroundColor = Color.Red, LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap };
            layout.Children.Add(label);
            this.Content = layout;

        }
    }
```

You can see that I create a StackLayout and a label and I bind the layout to the content. It works well and you can try it.